# AOP (AspectJ) : Is there a way to get context args of enclosing method within a handler advice?

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have an AspectJ *advice* whose *pointcut* is a `handler` type pointcut.

Here is the method containing the *join point* I want to advise:

```
public void foo(String p1) {
    try {
        // some code
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // more code    
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my aspect:

```
pointcut foopc(Exception ex) : handler(Exception) && args(ex) && withincode(public void foo(String));

before(Exception ex) : foopc(ex) {
    // advice body  
}
```

What I would like is to capture the variable `p1` and use it within the advice body (in addition to the exception `ex`).  Is this possible?  If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured it out.  If someone has a better answer or a more appropriate way of doing it I'll accept it over mine.

Code within the aspect:

```
pointcut fooExec(String p1) : 
    execution(public void foo(String)) && args(p1);

pointcut fooHandler(String p1, Exception ex) :
    cflow(fooExec(p1)) && handler(Exception) && args(ex)
    && withincode(public void foo(String));

before(String p1, Exception ex) : fooHandler(p1, ex) {
    // I can now use the variables p1 and ex.
}
```

EDIT:

I should point out that the signature within the `execution` could have simply been `* *(String)`, and the two pointcuts could have been combined into one like this:

```
pointcut fooHandler(String p1, Exception ex) :
    cflow(execution(* *(String) && args(p1))) 
    && handler(Exception) && args(ex)
    && withincode(public void foo(String));
```